# Как должна  выглядеть диаграмма состояний и переходов ?

Tags: uml, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как должны выглядеть данная диаграмма?

Сама диаграмма :
[image: Диаграмма]

Вот код:

```
void Base::process(){
    if (nextTime<=world::timeNow){
        switch (state){
        case bWait:
            if (world::countHeapWait>0 && qTruck.size()!=0){
                int nextTime=world::timeNow+load.getVal().workTime;
                world::countHeapWait--;
                load.getVal().nextWorkTime = nextTime+delayTime; 
                qTruck.getVal().setNextTime(nextTime);
                qTruck.getVal().state=tLoad;
                state = bLoad;
                (*this).nextTime=nextTime;
            }
            break;
        case bLoad:{
                load.getVal().count++;
                qTruck.pop();
                load.next();
                state=bWait;
                nextTime = load.getVal().nextWorkTime;
            }
            break;
        }
     }

void Truck::process(){
    srand(clock());
    if (nextTime<=world::timeNow){
        switch(state){
        case tLoad:{
            nextTime+=13+rand()%10;
            state =tRun;
        } 
            break;
        case tRun:{
            nextTime=world::maxWorkTime;
            state = tRazgr;
            count++;
            addTTQBase(*this,unload);
            }
            break;
        case tRazgr:{
            state = tWait;
            nextTime = world::maxWorkTime;
            addTTQBase(*this,base);
            }
            break;
    }   
   }
```

Так или по другому ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Этапы лучше размещать последовательно (в ряд или вертикально). Вообще лучше не "закручивать" всё это, а писать этапы один под/за другим, что-бы стрелки были прямыми.
2. Вторая — `Base::Process()` в начале. Если это функция, тогда она должна с чего-то выходить: либо из некого состояния (заокруглённый прямоугольник) или с точки (обьявление начала функции). Если же `Base::Process()` — это и есть начальное состояние, оно должно быть в заокругленном прямоугольнике.
3. Не понятно что такое `[timeNow==nextTime]`. Это аргументы выполнения процесса или что?

Эти ссылки, по-моему, хорошо показывают/обьясняют суть данного типа диаграм: [1](http://www.info-system.ru/designing/methodology/uml/theory/image/umlstate3.gif),[2](http://www.info-system.ru/designing/methodology/uml/theory/image/umlstate1.gif),[3](http://ertostik.net/images/stories/UML/state1.JPG),[4](http://ertostik.net/uml/diagramma-sostoyaniy-state-diagram.html).

Comment: Хм... эта блок-схема вроде как называется диаграмма.

Comment: Извините, я ошибся. Прогуглив, понял, что это совсем разные вещи.

----

В вашей диаграме тогда две проблемы: первая — та, что я и говорил, что лучше этапы размещать последовательно (в ряд или вертикально), а вторая — `Base::Process()` в начале. Если это функция, тогда она должна с чего-то выходить: либо из некого состояния (заокруглённый прямоугольник) или с точки (обьявление начала функции). Если же `Base::Process()` — это и есть начальное состояние, оно должно быть в заокругленном прямоугольнике.

Еще не понятно что такое `[timeNow==nextTime]`. Это аргументы выполнения процесса или что?

Comment: О, то что надо !